# Insertion Sort Optimization

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, insertion-sort

I'm trying to practice making some different sort functions and the insertion function that I came up with is giving me some trouble. I can sort lists that are less than 30K fairly quickly. But I have a list of 100K integers and it literally takes 15 minutes for the function to complete the sort. Everything is sorted correctly, but I don't believe it should take that long.

Am I missing something with my code that is making it take so long? Many thanks in advance.

```
void Sort::insertion_Sort(vector <int> v)
{
    int vecSize = v.size(); 

    //for loop to advance through the vector
    for (int i=0; i < vecSize; i++)
    {
        //delcare some variables 
        int cursor = i; 
        int inputCursor = i-1; 
        int temp = v[cursor]; 

        //check to see if we are considering only a single element 
        if (cursor > 0)
        {
            //if there is more than 1 element, then we test the following. 
            //1. is the cursor element less than the inputCursor(which 
            //is the previous element) 
            //2. is the input cursor greater than -1
            while (inputCursor > -1 && v[cursor] < v[inputCursor] )
            {

                    //if so, we swap the variables 
                    //then move the cursors back to check 
                    //the previous elment and see if we  need to swap again. 
                    temp = v[cursor];
                    v[cursor] = v[inputCursor];
                    v[inputCursor] = temp;
                    inputCursor--;
                    cursor--; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is fairly pointless to optimize an insertion sort. It is a quadratic algorithm.  Ignoring shortages of memory (leading to thrashing the virtual memory system), sorting 100k entries should take 11 times as long as sorting 30k entries.  Use a better algorithm — like quicksort or introsort.  It will perform noticably fast than insertion sort at 30k (probably at 1k), and dramatically so for 100k.

Comment: change the loop counter to (i=1;...) so you don't need `if (cursor > 0)` and the inputCursor>-1 in while .

Comment: You could quantify 'sorts 30k rows fairly quickly'. If it was less than a minute but the 100k rows was definitively over 15 minutes, then the difference is uncomfortably large. But there isn't much we can do to help you — you should still change the algorithm.  You might be finding that the vector mechanisms are strained as things get big.  You should really compare `std::sort()` with your 'optimized' insertion sort.  I think you'll be in for a surprise.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the i=1 is smart! :) Only reason I'm trying to do 100K is because a friend did the same file and his took under a minute to solve. Seems like I'm missing something that's really bogging down my function.

Comment: FWIW: I just ran a test with an insertion sort against quicksort, for random data sets in sizes from 10k integers to 100k in steps of 10k, written in C.  The 10k sorts took 1 ms for quick sort vs 40 ms for insertion sort; the 30k sorts took 3 ms vs 355 ms; the 100k sorts took 9 ms vs 3900 ms (3.9s).  That gives you two lots of perspective: (1) quick sort is enormously faster than insertion sort, and (2) 15 minutes for 100k integers is very slow, but so is any time in the minute range for 10k or 30k integers.  Testing on Mac OS X 10.9.3 with GCC 4.9.0.

Comment: Just NOTE, your code is too complicated for insertion sort. I recommend to look at other implementations.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is fairly pointless to optimize an insertion sort: It is a quadratic algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort is an `O(n^2)` algorithm.  It's slow for large inputs.  It's going to take roughly 11 times longer to process a list of 100k items than a list of 30k items.  For inputs larger than 20 or so, you should use something like quicksort, which is `O(n*log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

The `O(n^2)` vs `O(n*log(n))` problem, as pointed out by the other answer, is the center of this problem. I  would suggest a binary search algorithm, as it is more similar to the insert algorithm, and is simplier to implement. It would look for the point of insertion dividing the already inserted vector in half, and trying to see if the integer to be inserted is greater or not of the integer in the middle. Then, it will try again to split one of the half (the one on the choosen side) and so on, recursively.

I think this is the best approach without starting from scratch.